# C Programming - Sorting Last Iteration doesnt change anything

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I had a exercise to sort an array from left to right
on the left side there will be odd numbers and on the right side even numbers.

The Function Gets an (Array) and its size (n) and need to run on O(N).

in the last Comparison "4" to "-3" it's supposed to get in the first if but it doesnt for some reason i cant understand.

Thank you for the Help!

```
void main()
{
int n = 10, arr[] = { 6,-10,11,4,-3,21,40,16,-2,7 };
sort(arr, n);
}

void sort(int *arr, int n)

{
    int temp, i, MSB = 0, LSB = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n ; i++)

    if (((arr[MSB]) % 2 == 0) && (arr[n - 1 + LSB]) % 2 == 1)
    {
        temp = arr[MSB];
        arr[MSB] = arr[n - 1 + LSB];
        arr[n - 1 + LSB] = temp;
    }

    if (((arr[MSB] % 2) == 0) && ((arr[n - 1 + LSB]) % 2 == 0))
    {
        LSB--;
    }
    if (((arr[MSB] % 2) == 1) && ((arr[n - 1 + LSB]) % 2 == 0))
    {
        MSB++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe just a copy paste error: But you forgot the brackets after your for-loop

Comment: And you have this line twice "void sort(int *arr, int n)" ...  Please double check the code you posted, as @TobiSH said you may have a transcription error

Comment: there are other copy/paste errors BTW, but adding the brackets makes your code work OK I get "7 21 11 4 -3 -10 40 16 -2 6"

Comment: nothing that a debugger cannot help to figure out BTW (or even a couple of `printf`s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-3%2 gives -1 not 1; there was a ((arr[n - 1 + LSB]) % 2 == 0)) where it should be ((arr[n - 1 + LSB]) % 2 == 1)); the number of iterations can't be n, or you would exchange already exchanged couples: you should test for MSB+LSB < n; when the numbers are ok you should increment both LSB and MSB, and the same goes after you exchanged them; ...

This is a version that seems to be working. Sincerely I doubt someone made the previous code work as it was :)

https://onlinegdb.com/HkhLcDJuM

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void sort(int *arr, int n);

int main()
{
    int n = 10, arr[] = { 6,-10,11,4,-3,21,40,16,-2,7 };
    sort(arr, n);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {

        cout<<arr[i];
        cout<<" ";
    }


    return 0;
}

void sort(int *arr, int n)

{
    int temp, i, MSB = 0, LSB = 0;

    cout<<"START ";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {

        cout<<arr[i];
        cout<<" ";
    }
    cout<<" | ";
    cout<<MSB;
    cout<<" ... ";
    cout<<LSB;
    cout<<"\n";


    while (MSB-LSB<n) {

        if (((arr[MSB]) % 2 == 0) && ((arr[n - 1 + LSB]) % 2) != 0) {
            temp = arr[MSB];
            arr[MSB] = arr[n - 1 + LSB];
            arr[n - 1 + LSB] = temp;
            MSB++;
            LSB--;
        } else if (((arr[MSB] % 2) == 0) && (((arr[n - 1 + LSB]) % 2) == 0)) {
            LSB--;
        } else if (((arr[MSB] % 2) != 0) && (((arr[n - 1 + LSB]) % 2) != 0)) {
            MSB++;
        } else {
            MSB++;
            LSB--;
        }


        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {

            cout<<arr[i];
            cout<<" ";
        }
        cout<<" | ";
        cout<<MSB;
        cout<<" ... ";
        cout<<LSB;
        cout<<"\n";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax problems, for example:

```
void main()
{
    int n = 10, arr[] = { 6,-10,11,4,-3,21,40,16,-2,7 };
    sort(arr, n);}void sort(int *arr, int n)
}
```

1. `main` should be declared as one of these:

   - `int main(void);`
   - `int main(int argc, char **argv);`
   - `int main(int argc, char *argv[]);`

   `void main()` is not correct.
2. Moving the `void sort` part in a new line, you get

   ```
   void main()
   {
       int n = 10, arr[] = { 6,-10,11,4,-3,21,40,16,-2,7 };
       sort(arr, n);
   }

   void sort(int *arr, int n)
   }
   ```

   which is a syntax error. You should put the declaration of `sort` before `main`
   and end it with a semicolon:

   ```
   void sort(int *arr, int n);

   int main(void)
   {
       ...
   }
   ```
3. In `sort` your `for`-loop does not use `{ ... }` for the rest of the code,
   only the first `if` is executed in the loop.
4. Checking if a number is even with `number % 2 == 1` works only if number is
   positive, if number is negative, `number % 2 == -1`. Because `-3` is negative,
   the comparison fails and the code assumes that `-3` is even and doesn't get
   swapped with `4`. In this case I'd use `number % 2 != 0` for checking if
   `number` is odd.

   Another way of checking if a number is even is by doing `(number&1) == 0` and if
   it's odd by doing `(number&1) == 1`, this will work regardless of it being positive or
   negative. This is what I use in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int *arr, size_t n);

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 6,-10,11,4,-3,21,40,16,-2,7 };
    size_t len = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    sort(arr, len);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    putchar('\n');


    return 0;
}

void sort(int *arr, size_t n)
{
    int temp, MSB = 0, LSB = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {

        if (((arr[MSB] & 1) == 0) && ((arr[n - 1 + LSB] & 1) == 1))
        {
            temp = arr[MSB];
            arr[MSB] = arr[n - 1 + LSB];
            arr[n - 1 + LSB] = temp;
        }

        if (((arr[MSB] & 1) == 0) && ((arr[n - 1 + LSB] & 1) == 0))
        {
            LSB--;
        }

        if (((arr[MSB] & 1) == 1) && ((arr[n - 1 + LSB] & 1) == 0))
        {
            MSB++;
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me this output

```
$ ./a 
6 -10 11 4 -3 21 40 16 -2 7 
7 21 11 -3 4 -10 40 16 -2 6
```

Comment: Pablo Thank you!

Comment: its my first post so i didnt know exactly how to put the entire code in the article. the problem was that i didnt know how to opreate when given a negative number, i didnt know its different.